# Torque: Unauthorized Request

Tags: networking, server, hosts, torque

**Following this guide:**

https://jabriffa.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/installing-torquepbs-job-scheduler-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

I installed TORQUE on Ubuntu 16-04-lts (he claims the process works the same on 16.04)

**A short summary of his install instructions so this can be self sufficient:**

```
apt-get install torque-server torque-client torque-mom torque-pam
/etc/init.d/torque-mom stop
/etc/init.d/torque-scheduler stop
/etc/init.d/torque-server stop
pbs_server -t create

killall pbs_server

echo SERVER.DOMAIN > /etc/torque/server_name
echo SERVER.DOMAIN > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/acl_hosts
echo root@SERVER.DOMAIN > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/operators
echo root@SERVER.DOMAIN > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/managers

echo "SERVER.DOMAIN np=4" > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/nodes
echo SERVER.DOMAIN > /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config

/etc/init.d/torque-server start
/etc/init.d/torque-scheduler start
/etc/init.d/torque-mom start
# set scheduling properties
qmgr -c 'set server scheduling = true'
qmgr -c 'set server keep_completed = 300'
qmgr -c 'set server mom_job_sync = true
```

After following his directions up to:

```
qmgr -c 'set server scheduling = true'
```

I get the error message

```
qmgr obj=master.node svr=master.node: Unauthorized Request
```

I grep the logs as he mentions and find this unhelpful snippet: 
grep Unauthorized /var/spool/torque/server_logs/*

```
08/25/2018 15:48:43;0080;PBS_Server;Req;req_reject;Reject reply code=15007(Unauthorized Request ), aux=0, type=Manager, from root@master.node
```

This is my hostname:

```
master
```

This is my hosts file:

```
127.0.1.1 master master
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.136.7.155 master.node 
10.136.7.155 master 
10.136.65.29 slave1
10.136.73.247 slave2
10.136.44.128 slave3
```

This is how I configured the various config files:

```
echo master.node > /etc/torque/server_name
echo master.node > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/acl_hosts
echo root@master.node > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/operators
echo root@master.node > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/managers

echo "master.node np=4" > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/nodes
echo master.node > /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config
```

Each time I fiddle with it I restart the various daemons with:

```
/etc/init.d/torque-server restart
/etc/init.d/torque-scheduler restart
/etc/init.d/torque-mom restart
```

I am currently running as root.

**I am at a total loss as to what TORQUE wants here. Why am I unauthorized?**

Also qmgr thinks there are no nodes despite having a /var/spool/torque/server_priv/nodes file. Why?

```
Qmgr: list node
No Active Nodes, nothing done.
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from the same link and has the same error.

The problem is the server is running on the localhost hence if you specified an FQDN other than localhost, the request will appear to come from an unauthorized user.

I had to change server domain in my case to localhost:

```
echo localhost > /etc/torque/server_name
echo localhost > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/acl_hosts
echo root@localhost > /var/spool/torque/server_priv/acl_svr/operators
...
...
```